# How do I use installed Vim in Git Bash instead of the one that came with Git?

Tags: windows-7, vim, git

I've installed Vim and Git to `C:\Program Files (x86)\(vim|git)` respectively.

When I run Vim from Git Bash, it runs the internal version of Vim that came with the Git installer. Is there a way to override this behavior that doesn't involve changing my `.profile` or `.bashrc` or the like so that I can run the version of Vim that I installed in Program Files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default Git runs vim from `Git\bin\vim`.
This is actually a script that contains path to the executable itself:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /share/vim/vim73/vim "$@"
```

Therefore you can edit this file to point to your Git location.

The default editor can be overridden in `Git\etc\gitconfig`:

```
[core]
editor = path_to_your_editor
```

Comment: On the off chance that somebody comes here after 2012-08-17, the path to the `gitconfig` file on a `chocolately` git install is `c:\program files\git\ningw64\etc\gitconfig`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that changing content of `C:\Program Files (x86)\{vim,git}` is possible you have at least these two options depending on value of your `%PATH%` environment variable:

1. If you have `C:\Program Files (x86)\vim\vim73` in your `%PATH%` you can just remove `vim` binary that was installed with Git. For this to work Vim should be run as `vim` and not by a full path.
2. You probably have your `Program Files (x86)` directory on a NTFS volume, so you can remove Vim executable installed by Git and make a symbolic link to real Vim executable.

Answer (score 3):

If your installation of Vim is available on path, open up Powershell console and execute this:

`git config --global core.editor "$(Get-Command vim | % { $_.Source -replace '\\','\\\\' })"`

It will set your git editor to Vim that is on path.

Comment: That will work within Git. I was looking for an option that will use the system-installed version of Vim within Git Bash.The accepted answer works best still.

Comment: @sirlancelot i think, I misread your question.